# Correct technique to estimate cumulative baseline hazard function in R?

Tags: r, survival

I am hoping to simulate survival times from a lung transplant dataset (n > 20,000). In order to do this I need an estimate of the cumulative baseline hazard function.

I have used the `basehaz` function in R and then fit a Weibull distribution to it using `nls`. However the resulting simulated survival times are significantly lower than the (88% censored) dataset:
[image: Estimate cumulative hazard using basehaz results in lower survival times]

The second technique I used is to fit a Weibull distribution (again using `nls`) directly to the survival function given by the KM curve. This results in survival curves that match, however I'm not sure of the "correctness" of the survival times since the training dataset is heavily censored and the generated survival times are not censored.

What is the most correct technique to estimate the cumulative baseline hazard function and generate realistic survival times for heavily censored survival data?

**Additional details, see response below**

1. I use basehaz with centered = FALSE, would this help address the problem of predictions at the means?
2. Using survreg I've found that an exponential distribution fits much better than a Weibull distribution, I'm guessing I can't just find which value of lambda matches the survival curve when exp(-lambda * time) is plotted?
3. I can generate survival times using -(log(U) / (lambda * HR)), where U is a uniform random number in (0, 1] - how would I know if the value of lambda used is appropriate to my survival dataset?

The model has 4 continuous variables, 3 of which are fit with restricted cubic splines and 1 categorical variable with 4 levels.

To simulate the survival times I want to take in a list of patients with the corresponding variables listed above, and then calculate the linear predictor and thus the hazard ratio to generate survival times as in (3) above.

**Possible solution, looking for feedback**

Thank you very much for the help so far, I feel I have a better idea of what I am doing now. Here is the full process I went through, if it sounds correct please let me know and I can update this post.

I started by using the `cph` method from the `rms` package and built a Cox model:

`rc <- cph(Surv(pdata$waittime, pdata$death_cens) ~ o2_listing + group + rcs(func_status) + rcs(bmi_listing) + rcs(pa_mean), pdata, y=T, x=T)`

I then built a dataframe that I planned to use as a reference/baseline:

```
tmpdf <- data.frame(
  o2_listing = mean(pdata$o2_listing),
  group = "A",
  func_status = median(pdata$func_status),
  bmi_listing = mean(pdata$bmi_listing),
  pa_mean = mean(pdata$pa_mean)
)
```

I decided to use the mean value for the continuous variables, the median value for functional status (this is a numeric variable but it takes discrete values) and the reference group "A" for the categorical variable.

I then used `survfit` and passed the reference dataframe to it using `newdata` and then fit a Weibull distribution to the cumulative hazard function:

```
sv <- survfit(rc, newdata = tmpdf)

DF <- data.frame(time = sv$time, hazard = sv$cumhaz)
fit <- nls(DF$hazard ~ l * DF$time ^ v, data=DF, algorithm="port", start=list(l=0.001, v = 1))
l <- coef(fit)[1]
v <- coef(fit)[2]
```

Plotting the survival function for the reference group and overlaying the Weibull curve shows a good fit:

[image: Weibull curve fit to reference group]

The next step is to calculate the linear predictor (LP) for the reference group:

`predict(rc, newdata=tmpdf)`

`-0.4337017`

Survival times are generated using the following function: `(-(log(U))/(l * exp(LP)))^(1/v)`

The value of the linear predictor will shift the curve, however since `l` and `v` were calculated with a reference group with a linear predictor of `-0.4337017` this needs to be subtracted from the LP that is being simulated.

So here is an example, updating the dataframe to specific values:

```
tmpdf <- data.frame(
  o2_listing = 6,
  group = "D",
  func_status = 50,
  bmi_listing = 32,
  pa_mean = 15
)
```

Again the LP can be calculated: `predict(rc, newdata=tmpdf)` which returns `0.01615275`.

The survival curve can then be plotted using the updated dataframe, then the simulated curve can be overlayed like so:

`lines(exp(-l * DF$time^v * exp(0.01615275 - -0.4337017)) ~ DF$time)`

This results in the following fit for a new "simulated" individual:
[image: Simulated survival curve using new technique]

If this appears correct please let me know and I'll update this to hopefully save time for anybody else who needs to simulate survival times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just what the "baseline" for the "baseline hazard function" is. If you define that carefully, you will be OK. The way that you describe what you've done suggests that you fell into a trap. From the help page for `basehaz()`:

> This function is simply an alias for `survfit`, which does the actual work and has a richer set of options. The alias exists only because some users look for predicted survival estimates under this name...If there are factor variables in the model, then the default predictions at the "mean" are meaningless since they do not correspond to any possible subject; correct results require use of the newdata argument of `survfit`.

Thus I suspect that what `basehaz()` returned didn't represent any realistic combination of covariate values. As the manual page suggests, it's safest to specify your own set of covariate values via the `newdata` argument to `survfit()` so that you know exactly what your baseline represents.

Furthermore, you can't safely compare the raw Kaplan-Meier curve to any specific baseline hazard, regardless of which covariate values you specify for the baseline. The mean of survivals (one crude way to think about the Kaplan-Meier curve) is not the same as survival at mean covariate values, given the inherent nonlinearity of survival models. That also means there is a danger in using a Weibull baseline estimate based on the raw Kaplan-Meier curve.

If you want to work with a Weibull baseline hazard, why not just fit a full Weibull survival model directly? The R `survreg()`function does that quite simply. It will return the location and scale parameters for a defined "baseline" model and the coefficients that represent the change in location as covariate values change.

*In response to edited question*

If you specify `centered = FALSE` to `basehaz()` then you get the baseline hazard with all covariate values set to 0. That can make it easier to set up calculations for any particular set of covariate values than you have with the default of `centered = TRUE`. The behavior of `basehaz()` can depend on the specific software used; a quick test suggests that `cph` and `coxph` objects return different results with the default. It might be that `cph` objects internally specify `centered = FALSE`, but you should check the documentation.

For parametric modeling, it's not clear why you "found that an exponential distribution fits much better than a Weibull distribution." The exponential is a specific case of the Weibull, with the `scale` parameter (in the location-scale format) forced to take a value of 1. I wonder if there's some other problem here. An exponential or Weibull model provides an (Intercept) that corresponds to baseline values of the covariates, which you then can translate to a rate constant. With the R `survreg()` function and an exponential model, the exponential rate constant  $\lambda = \text{exp}(-(\text{Intercept})) $. Be careful, particularly with Weibull, as parameterizations vary.

If you have the correct baseline value of $\lambda$ at reference covariate values, then your formula for simulation seems OK. You can save yourself a lot of trouble by using the R [`simsurv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=simsurv), which is designed for this purpose. For censored data you also have to simulate censoring times for all cases, then choose the lower of the event or censoring time as the time outcome, labeled accordingly.

Comment: I have a few follow-up questions:
1) I use basehaz with centered = FALSE, would this help address the problem of predictions at the means?
2) Using survreg I've found that an exponential distribution fits much better than a Weibull distribution, I'm guessing I can't just find which value of  lambda matches the survival curve when exp(-lambda * time) is plotted?
3) I can generate survival times using -(log(U) / (lambda * HR)), where U is a uniform random number in (0, 1] - how would I know if the value of lambda used is appropriate to my survival dataset?

Comment: @SamKennedy we try to make this site useful to later visitors with similar questions. To that end, please edit your original question to include the critical parts of your comment. It's simplest just to add to the end of the question, with a heading noting that the addition is in response to an answer. Also, please clarify in that edited question whether your Cox, Weibull, and exponential models involved covariates; if so, about how many of each type (especially continuous versus binary versus multi-level categorical) and if you want the simulations to include covariates.

Comment: I've updated the question, hopefully it clarifies the simulation process and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my question with a possible solution, if it looks good please let me know and I'll mark your answer as accepted and update my post. Thank you so much for your help!